# A dog that was running about the streets of a little town was brown

Tags: definite-article

> A dog that was running about **the streets of a little town** was
> brown.

Is it mandatory to use "the"? Would this be correct?

> A dog that was running about **streets of a little town** was
> brown.

Comment: A most unlikely sentence (why not say "A brown dog was running..."?), but, yes, we say _the streets_.

Comment: Would it be a mistake to say "about streets of a little town"?

Comment: @user1425 It would certainly be unnatural.  We're not talking about streets in general, we're talking about specific streets - the ones belonging to this town.  For that reason, the zero article would be a very strange choice.

Comment: That's true. But the dog didn't run along ALL OF THEM.

Comment: @KateBunting "a brown dog ..." Not necessarily. There may be some reason why the writer wants to call out that the dog was brown. Like, "You claim that it was my dog that was running around the streets? No, my dog is yellow. The dog that was running around the streets was brown."

Comment: @user1425 True but irrelevant. The writer is saying that the dog was running around these specific streets. He didn't say he covered all of them. If it was important, you'd have to add words to specify. "The dog that was running around some of the streets ..." or "The dog that ran around every steet ..."

Comment: @Jay - Yes, if it was "_The_ dog", but it sounds odd starting with "_A_ dog" (implying that the dog hasn't been mentioned before).